# Difference between Visual Studio Redistributable and Visual Studio SP1

Tags: visual-studio

Are there many redistributable packages?  If so, how do I know which package to download?

Comment: Is this for you, or for deploying software?

Comment: they can reside side-by-side.  Get both from MSDownloads for personal use.

Comment: @Jess, for me on my workstation.

Comment: Then see my answer/links below.  You probably already have all the redistributables you need.  If you are developing a .net application for an older framework, then you might need to download an older version.

Comment: The redistributables just contain the libraries necessary for your programs to run (e.g. Math.Pow, String.Trim).  Service packs will fix bugs in those libraries (and/or add functionality).  When you install VS2010, it installs the versions necessary for your programs to run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need the redistributables for any of the environments you develop in.  Note the "full" versions for the .net Frameworks contain both 32-bit and 64-bit versions.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5a4x27ek.aspx

You can select other versions (.net 3.5, etc) from the "Other versions" link at the top of the page.

For C++, the VC2010 redistributables are here:

x86 -  http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=a7b7a05e-6de6-4d3a-a423-37bf0912db84

x64 - http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=BD512D9E-43C8-4655-81BF-9350143D5867

Comment: The VS2010 SP1, is actually an update (bug fixes) for Visual Studio 2010.  This does not contain updates for the redistributables because there aren't any yet.  However, older SP for VS2008 did include updates for the .net Framework redistributables.

Answer (score 1):

The visual studio SP1 redistributable fixes issues (bugs) in visual studio and updates the security
-> Use this if you have VS and want to update

The visual studio redistributable puts updated versions of assemblies, packages and dlls on your machine
-> Use these if you have programs that depend on the updated packages

Answer (score 0):

If using InstallShield, you should update your MSMs to point to the new Visual C++ libraries.