# Why VC++ is required for tensorflow while not for numpy?

Tags: numpy, tensorflow, visual-c++

This may sound like dumb but after working in python for so many years, I want to understand why numpy gets installed while tensorflow asks for Microsoft VC++ to get installed in Windows. Common knowledge says both are written in C++. Then why former package is getting installed without any problem,while the later asks for VC++?

Comment: Most of us don't build `numpy` from source; we install versions with precompiled binaries (via `ancadonda, pip, etc).  The respective install documentations should explain the requirements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The VC++ requirement exists since version 2.1. The [release notes of the version 2.1](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/releases/tag/v2.1.0) states:

> **Windows users:** Officially-released tensorflow Pip packages are now
> built with Visual Studio 2019 version 16.4 in order to take advantage
> of the new /d2ReducedOptimizeHugeFunctions compiler flag. To use these
> new packages, you must install "Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable
> for Visual Studio 2015, 2017 and 2019", available from Microsoft's
> website here.
>
> - This does not change the minimum required version for building TensorFlow from source on Windows, but builds enabling
>   EIGEN_STRONG_INLINE can take over 48 hours to compile without this
>   flag. Refer to configure.py for more information about
>   EIGEN_STRONG_INLINE and /d2ReducedOptimizeHugeFunctions.
> - If either of the required DLLs, msvcp140.dll (old) or msvcp140_1.dll (new), are missing on your machine, import tensorflow
>   will print a warning message.

This change makes the Windows tensorflow package depends on some C++ API that are not available by default on a Windows machine. You can read more about it on that question: [Why does my application require Visual C++ Redistributable package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16167305/why-does-my-application-require-visual-c-redistributable-package)