# Making a C++ dll using VS2013 and calling methods from Delphi XE6; C++ dll has some VS or .NET dependency

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013, dll, delphi-xe6

TIA.

I have made a c++ dll using VS 2013 which is being called from Delphi XE6. All works fine. When make a Delphi exe and I try to run it on any system that doesn't have VS3013, my exe fails with Access Violation(Access violation at address 00A8451E in module *.exe. Read of address 83EC8B69.) The same thing works and on my system (development machine) and any machine with VS2013.

The DLL i have made is a dynamic dll. I have also tried to use the option "/MTd for Debug" in project settings as suggested in the link below. I also installed "Visual C++ Redistributable Packages for Visual Studio 2013" suggested in the same link. None of them helped. Please suggest.

Link:
[How to leave Visual Studio 2013 dlls dependencies behind?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21602007/how-to-leave-visual-studio-2013-dlls-dependencies-behind)

Comment: Suggest debug or review code. "Debugging" by changing environment "lets work" is  bad policy. In intensive C++ times we speak to customer "problem is in your environment" for every exception, but deep feel that problem is in our code. Do You have knowledge or imagination which lines / part of DLL give exception?

Comment: What sense You give to words "dynamic dll" ? Dynamic sequence of calling?

Comment: Hi Thanks for the reply. I have made a dynamic dll project in vs2013. I am able to compile and use the dll properly. Calling the dll from Delphi alsl works finr. There is no problem with calling methods in dll. The issue is I want  to remove dependency or rather find the dependency. There is no exception or anything while running the Delphi application in my system or any system vs2013 but when this Delphi application exe is transferred to any other system with no vs2013 the issue happens. I am not sure if I have still made my self clear?

Comment: With Dynamic DLLs, I just mean I have created dyminc dll project in vs2013 and the DLL i create has two dependent dlls which are being used dynamically in the c++ code and when calling my dll from Delphi application from my system(which has vs2013), the app works fine i.e. it calls my dll which will dynamically call other two dependent dlls placed along with the delphi exe. All this works fine in any system with vs2013.

Comment: 1. Sorry, my 2013 Studio Community, i haven't "dynamic dll" wizard. All DLL at general are "dynamic"  (<> static LIB), plus different way of use DLL at runtime "more dynamic"  so is base to my un-understanding 2. Usually programmer (C++ programmer) feel what parts of code have higher risk.

Comment: @JacekCz..Thanks for the help. The code is just from this link which says- "Basic Example". This call is hapenning fine and I am able to get results. My issue is somehting is with dependency of the delphi app with vs2013. Link: https://code.google.com/p/tesseract-ocr/wiki/APIExample

Comment: Can some help please ?