# How can I run a .exe file on any Windows computer?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, exe

My friend wanted me to make him this program and he is not very tech savvy. How can I make the .exe run without making him download anything extra? It was coded in C++ on Visual Studio.

Comment: Nope, you need to distribute the runtime.

Comment: So what have you done so far?

Comment: You can link everything statically, but then the executable can get a bit large.

Comment: Well is there another file type I can convert it to? Like .iso? I don't necessarily need it to be an .exe but I want it to run in the command prompt and function as it is intended.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If your program uses anything from the standard library, it will need the Visual C++ runtime library, which is typically loaded from the library DLLs (something like `msvcr110.dll`).

However you can instruct the <s>compiler</s> (the *linker*, rather) to include (I do not mean #include-ing the header file) the library as part of your executable (`exe` file). (I guess you thought of ISO because an archive file would include all the necessary DLLs) According to https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2kzt1wy3.aspx, use the /MT compiler option will cause the "multithreaded, static version" of the Visual C++ runtime library (which is the library in pre-compiled code) to be included in your program during linking (in contrast to the default /MD option, which only causes code that helps your program link to the main library DLL to be included).

**Correction**: The program will be larger, but since the linker does not actually add *everything* to the output program, the size of the output file depends on what the program uses. [Microsoft Visual Studio ~ C/C++ Runtime Library ~ Static/dynamic linking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14749662/microsoft-visual-studio-c-c-runtime-library-static-dynamic-linking) This might be helpful. (If you are interested, look into `Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\lib` (don't forget to replace the version number).)

Go to project settings -> configuration properties -> C/C++ -> code generation and set `runtime library` to `Multi-threaded (MT)`.

**Correction**: it seems directly setting the compiler flag **will** work even with the default /MD or /MDd flag left in the command line.

**EDIT**: be sure to clean the solution (build -> clean solution) after applying these settings. Otherwise the linker may still try to use the old files.