# Make visual studio compile so that the end user doesn't need c++ run-time libraries

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I need to make a program that is stand alone and I currently have it working on my computer compiled with Visual studio but when I move the build folder to another computer it says that MSVCP120.dll is missing. I cannot use an installer in this case so is there a way to make it not have those dependencies. One option I have is to switch the project over to code::blocks but that will take a while.

Comment: This may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14749662/microsoft-visual-studio-c-c-runtime-library-static-dynamic-linking

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem a couple of days ago and I thought it's only because you try to build your project in Debug mode.

Actually, you can statically link the runtime to your project and get rid of the libraries by setting the ***/MT*** flag in your project properties: **Project > [YourProjectName] Properties > Configuration Properties > C/C++ > Code Generation > Runtime Library.**

Small note: Be careful with the option you select, make sure you apply this settings only to **Release**. If you need Debug mode, set the ***/MTd*** flag instead.

Comment: /MTd for debug version

Comment: Debug versions aren't appropriate for end users. You may want to check your MSVC license whether you are even **allowed** to give debug builds to end users.