# What does a VC++ executable need in order to run?

Tags: windows, visual-c++, executable

I am new to VC++, etc . Could the learned viewer let me know - what does a Visual C++ executable need in order to run ? We want to create a product in VC++, we would like to know when it is installed and run on a bare minimum Windows machine, will it require any other software ?

Answer (score 3):

The respective *Visual C++ Redistributable Packages* are not installed by default with Windows but will be required to run VC++ executables unless statically including the runtime library.

Have a look at [Microsoft Visual Studio ~ C/C++ Runtime Library ~ Static/dynamic linking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14749662/microsoft-visual-studio-c-c-runtime-library-static-dynamic-linking) for some more information on the difference between having the runtime statically included or using the dll.

See [the latest supported Visual C++ downloads](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2977003) for downloading redistributable packages for Visual C++.

Comment: Thank you. But Is this already present in a default Windows installation? I have a Windows installation on my machine that has VC++, so should I conclude default environment to run a basic level (dll type) VC++ application is present on a Windows installation.

Comment: @user4127664: no, the Visual Studio runtimes are not included in Windows.  See http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2014/04/11/10516280.aspx