# Preprocessing multiple source files with one command using g++

Tags: c++, ubuntu, makefile, compiler-errors, g++

## Question

I have three files in my current working directory:

- `hello.cpp`
- `goodbye.cpp`
- `prog.cpp`

I would like to **only** preprocess `hello.cpp` and `goodbye.cpp` and dump the output in files `hello.i` and `goodbye.i`. Is there a way to achieve this using `g++` in a Ubuntu Linux command line *using one command*? The reason I would like to call `g++` only once is because I would eventually like to include this command in my own Makefile.

## What I've tried

I basically did the following:

`g++ -E -o goodbye.i hello.i goodbye.cpp hello.cpp`

Which, unsurprisingly, failed with the following error:

> g++ : fatal error: cannot specify '-o' with '-c', '-S' or '-E' with multiple files
> compilation terminated

I also tried `g++ -E goodbye.cpp hello.cpp`, which only reminded me that the preprocessor dumps to stdout by default. I do, for the purposes of this exercise, need for `g++` to dump the result into an actual `*.i` file...

## What I'm trying to avoid

From the comments, it seems to me that I can provide a further clarification. I'm trying to avoid having multiple commands in my Makefile, as each separate `.cpp` file would generate a separate command:

```
all: preprocess_hello preprocess_goodbye

preprocess_hello:
    g++ -E -o hello.i hello.cpp

preprocess_hello:
    g++ -E -o goodbye.i goodbye.cpp
```

Obviously, this is not ideal, because every new file I add would require adding a new command and updating the `all` target.

Comment: "[B]ecause I would eventually like to include this command in my own Makefile" seems like a strange reason. Why does it have to be *one* command because of that?

Comment: What prevents you from writing two lines of command to preprocess each of file? Makefiles accepts multiple lines of command.

Comment: @molbdnilo because I might have 100 files. Should I then write 100 commands?

Comment: @user32882 you can make one rule that applies to multiple files but processes one file at a time. Can you explain what you are trying to do? maybe show your makefile so far?

Comment: @user253751 I don't have a Makefile yet, but I believe the question is clear enough as it is. Making one rule that applies to multiple files but processes one file at a time does sound promising. Would you demonstrate how I can do that with my simple example above?

Comment: @user32882 you should elaborate on the restriction about 100 files. That might be the point.

Comment: @LouisGo What aspect about the restriction would you like for me to elaborate on exactly?

Comment: A bigger picture like "I want to preprocess a bunch of files and generated each `*.i`" or so. Then we could provide more solutions to your question. Indeed what @user253751 said might be the correct direction, but more context is helpful.

Comment: What is the purpose of the .i file?

Comment: @LouisGo please see edit to my question where I clearly show what I'm trying to avoid and why.

Comment: @user253751 it contains preprocessed C++ code.

Comment: I believe what @user253751 meant is that what would you like to do with `*.i` files. Are you parsing inside makefile or having another script triggered to parse...etc. Also you might want to add a tag for makefile.

Comment: If the point is to just generate .i files for all .cpp files, only one time, then you don't even really need make and you can probably do it with a shell script, although it's not difficult with make.

Comment: @LouisGo I would like to turn them into object files and then archive them into a static library. I don't have any shell scripts, just a Makefile and the indicated files, as mentioned in my question.

Comment: @user253751 if it's not difficult with Make like you say, then please post an answer showing me how to do it.

Comment: @user32882 most people turn .cpp files directly into .o files - it's pretty unusual to use .i in the middle

Comment: I think you should find yourself a more substantial introduction to `make` than whatever you're using now.

Comment: That said I'd use `.i` with some error checking scripts like: "Do my source file handling all the nums declared in the header". While a static library is an archive of `.o`s which are the result of compilation units. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34479664/4123703).

Comment: Just to answer the exact question asked: there's no way to get a single invocation of the compiler (at least not any compiler I'm aware of, including GCC and clang) to process multiple input `.c` files and generate multiple output `.i` files.  It's not something the compiler can do.  Using a pattern rule such as in the answer below is the right approach.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a [pattern rule](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Pattern-Rules.html) so Make knows how to generate a .i file from a .c file:

```
%.i: %.cpp
    g++ -E -o $@ $<
```

and then if your makefile ever requires `hello.i`, Make will know that it can use the command `g++ -E -o hello.i hello.cpp`

E.g. if you have `all: hello.i goodbye.i` and run `make all` it will know that it needs hello.i and goodbye.i and it will make them.

---

If you have a list of .cpp files and you need to convert it to a list of .i files (e.g. if you want to do `all: $(CPPFILES)` but it doesn't work because those are the .cpp files and not the .i files) you can use [patsubst](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Text-Functions.html):

```
all: $(patsubst %.cpp,%.i,$(CPPFILES))
```

You can even use [wildcard](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/File-Name-Functions.html#File-Name-Functions) to get the list of cpp files. To make `all` depend on all the .i files for all the .cpp files in the current directory, you could use

```
all: $(patsubst %.cpp,%.i,$(wildcard *.cpp))
```

Comment: This smells like the right answer. I'll do some research and accept it when I get it to work. Thanks for taking the time.