# Does c++ dll imported in to c# application need to have c++ run time libary?

Tags: c#, c++, pinvoke, dllimport

I have added the c++ dll in to my c# application by using the(Dllimport)Pinvoke functionality.I have build the project with vs2015 with Microsoft Redistributing Visual C++ Files and it worked fine and then i have copied the generated bin folder in to another machine it doesn't have visual studio and visual c++ files but the still sample is working.

Are c++ run time library are mandatory for using imported dll in C++ application? or when building the application will the c++ run time library be added as a resource in a dll?

Comment: It depends how you built the DLL. Does it link to the runtime dynamically, or statically? That was a choice you made.

Comment: Building the DLL with /MT is okay if the DLL does not use any other DLLs.

Comment: i am accessing the c++ dll in c# application by providing the dll path in dllimport during the runtime.

Comment: C# doesn't matter to this question here, it depends on how the C++ DLL is built as suggested by David Hefferman.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14752373/1300910

Comment: When you built the DLL, how did you link the runtime? That's a setting determined in the project options in VS.

Comment: Thanks for the stackoverflow link the msvcp110.dll has been installed in the  machine in the c drive windows folders which is equivalent to  C++ standard library.so the sample is working fine with out c++ run time library

Comment: Installing the redistributable is a one time thing. So if a computer has installed *any* program (Office, web browser, game, utility, whatever) using a specific compiler version, any other program built using the same compiler will also work.

Comment: You still don't seem to have grasped that you need to know whether your linked to the runtime statically or dynamically. You have to know that information. Why don't you know it?